# Iframe and CSS - Embedded YouTube Videos show annoying black frame

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, border

I know this problem has been discussed before - but unfortunately can't I find the right solution for my "tiny" problem. I am running a Wordpress-Blog ([www.freiheitenwelt.de](http://www.freiheitenwelt.de/blog)) that includes 16:9 YouTube Videos as well. To make things responsive I included this well know CSS code into my script.

```css
.article-video {
position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height:0;
 overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
      
}

.article-video iframe, .video-container object, .article-video embed {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
        
}
```

The Iframe was already set in the Premium-Theme that I bought. But the CSS class was still missing. ?!?! Strange thing! Anyhow. This is the code of the video.php.

```html
<div class="article-video">
   <?php if ($post->post_type == 'portfolio') {
    echo wp_oembed_get($embed, array('width'=> 1110, 'height'=> 624)); 
   }
   
   else {
    echo wp_oembed_get($embed, array('width'=> 700, 'height'=> 394)); 
   }
   ?>
  </div>
```

The responsive functions are working just well. The only thing that still annoys me are the two black borders on top and the bottom of my videos. I tried playing around with padding-top, margin, width adjustments and more. But I can't get it solved....

Here a picture about it!

Any help welcome! Different Webpages speak about the as the solution for removing the black borders... In my case this doesn't work and I somehow think there is something else running in the background that maybe disturbed the CSS. I am not a good programmer. Basic stuff and with help I can figure out thins - but there are a lot of unknown...

Thanks in advance...

Martin - Greetings from Colombia

[Borders in Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYP3s.jpg)

Comment: Make the width of the video a little wider and the video will fill in the black borders. The video is a specific ratio. Given that if you make the video smaller in width but keep the height the same the black borders will get bigger.

Comment: Hi there, 

the maximum I can use is 710 for the Blog-Posts. 

On the Main page videos just have a width of 510. 

I played around within the video.php - but it doesn't change a thing...

Comment: If you cant change the width or do not want to mess with it then just adjust the height in your css to there is no black bars